# Combine multiple rows to one row per group

Tags: r, group-by, sum

I feel like my problem is an easy one to solve, however, I can't seem to figure it out.

I want to combine multiple rows that belong to the same group so that per group there is one row. This row has the sum over the rows for some variables and the mean for other variables. In the example, I only included variable `treatment` of which I need the sum across the rows of each group `episode`.

```
Df <- data.frame(country = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B","B", "B", "B"),
                 year = c("1950", "1951", "1952", "1953", "1954", "1950", "1951", "1952", "1953"), 
                 time1 = c("1950", "1951", "1951", "1953", "1954", "1950", "1951", "1952", "1952"), 
                 time2 = c("1951", "1953", "1953", "1954", "1955", "1951", "1952", "1954", "1954"),
                 episode = c("1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "3"),
                 status = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
                 treatment = c(10, "NA", 20, 5, "NA", "NA", 30, 100, 10))

Df2 <- data.frame(country = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                   time1 = c("1950", "1951", "1953", "1954", "1950", "1951", "1952"), 
                   time2 = c("1951", "1953", "1954", "1955", "1951", "1952", "1954"),
                   episode = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3"),
                   status = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                   treatment = c(10, 20, 5, 0, 0, 30, 110))
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: How are you defining what is a "group"? Is it country+episode? How did you decide which time values to include in the reduced data set?

Comment: Is `Df2` your desired output?

Comment: @TarJae yes, Df2 is my desired output.

Comment: @MrFlick yes, a group is country+episode.

Comment: @Carmela Please see my update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: After clarification see comments:

1. Column `treatment` is `character`. With `type.convert(as.is=TRUE)` we transform it to `integer`.
2. Then we group and after that
3. we use `summarise` with `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
Df %>% 
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(country, time1, time2, episode, status) %>%
  summarise(treatment = sum(treatment, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
  country time1 time2 episode status treatment
  <chr>   <int> <int>   <int>  <int>     <int>
1 A        1950  1951       1      0        10
2 A        1951  1953       2      1        20
3 A        1953  1954       3      0         5
4 A        1954  1955       4      1         0
5 B        1950  1951       1      1         0
6 B        1951  1952       2      0        30
7 B        1952  1954       3      1       110
```

First answer:

```
library(dplyr)
Df %>% 
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(episode) %>% 
  summarise(sumTreatment=sum(treatment, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
  episode sumTreatment
    <int>        <int>
1       1           10
2       2           50
3       3          115
4       4            0
```

Comment: Great! Now, if I have more variables than in Df/Df2, how can I summarize with different operations for different variables? Let's say I need the `sum` for `treatment` and the `mean` for a variable called `population`, is there a way to do that?

Comment: `Df %>% 
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise(treatment = sum(treatment, na.rm = TRUE),
            population_mean = mean(population, na.rm=TRUE))`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library(tidyverse)    
Df2 %>% filter(!is.na(treatment))%>%group_by(episode) %>% summarise(sumTreatment = sum(treatment))
```

Comment: If I add `country` to the group, then it looks very good. However, it drops the other variables like `time1`and `time2` which I will still need in the data frame. Do you have an idea how I can keep those variables?